# How drag and drop will be perfomed in the Winapp driver.?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, winappdriver

I am working on Outlook where i need to drag one email and drop it into 2nd folder.

I tired below code:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.ClickAndHold(from).MoveToElement(to).Release().Build().Perform();
Or
builder.DragAndDrop(from, to).MoveToElement(to).Build().Perform();
```

With this i can perform click and Hold mouse operation but email is not getting moved to drop in 2nd folder.

Answer (score 0):

Next IWebElement DragAndDrop [extension](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/issues/1223#issuecomment-741770991) working for me:

```
public static void DragAndDrop(this IWebElement source, IWebElement destination)
{
    var destinationCenterX = destination.Location.X + destination.Size.Width / 2;
    var destinationCenterY = destination.Location.Y + destination.Size.Height / 2;
    var action = new Actions(source.GetDriver());
    action.MoveToElement(source).Build().Perform();
    action.ClickAndHold(source).MoveByOffset(destinationCenterX, destinationCenterY).Build().Perform();
    destination.Click();
    action.Release().Perform();
}
```